# Track updated columns postgresql trigger?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers, postgresql-9.3

I am using postgreSQL and I have tables on which I use triggers to get notified of changes on tables.

Now, I have a usecase where when an update on a table is done, I want to notify only the updated columns of my table. So if my table has 10 columns and only 5 get updated I need to notify only of 5 updated columns.

One approach would be use OLD and NEW on every column and compare. This would lead to a separate function for each table.

Is there any functionality in postgreSQL pertianing to such a case?

Comment: You could use `hstore`  or `json`  to detect the changes. See here http://okbob.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/most-simply-implementation-of-history.html or here http://8kb.co.uk/blog/2015/01/19/copying-pavel-stehules-simple-history-table-but-with-the-jsonb-type/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: First link is not working. `jsonb` is in PostgreSQL 9.4 and I have 9.3. Is there a solution in 9.3 for the usecase?

Comment: The first link works for me without problems. If you do want to use the json solution then why not upgrade to 9.5?

Answer (score 0):

You can create triggers in [pl/tcl](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/pltcl-trigger.html) or [pl/perl](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plperl-triggers.html).

Both produce all the information about the context of the table that triggers the function in a bunch of variables, and OLD and NEW are associative arrays, so you have a lot of freedom to do whatever you like. Eg:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION valid_id() RETURNS trigger AS $$
  my ($new, $old) = ($_TD->{new}, $_TD->{old});
  my (@allflds) = keys %$new;
  my (@changed) = grep { $new->{$_} ne %$old->{$_} } @allflds;

  my (%difold, %difnew);

  %difold = map { _$ => $old->{_$} } @changed;
  %difnew = map { _$ => $new->{_$} } @changed;

  ... notify the values in %difold and %difnew as you need ...
$$ LANGUAGE plperl;
```